# Long select is taking 55 secs to display the result, better way to consult?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

### Introduction

Hi everyone, i'm trying to get a large select but i'm having a principal problem, this query is taking over 55 secs to display 13,000 rows because there are 4 sub-query (searching to the same table) they are:

1. PARENT LINK SO AUT
2. PARENT LINK SO LINE AUT
3. PLSO AUT CREATED DATE
4. PLSO AUT SHIPPED DATE

These 4 columns only will get data when **DEM_TYPE** is *'WO'*, that's the reason why i put in each sub-query **CASE WHEN**.

If **DEM_TYPE** is not 'WO' those 4 Columns will be NULL

I just need the first row found it in the sub-query, that's the reason why i used TOP 1.

Next i'll show you the query and the result of the table

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  IDX_TMP
    ON ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY(ROWID);
    SELECT ONE.ROWID, ONE.PLANNER, ONE.BUYER, ONE.DEM_TYPE, ONE.DEM_SOURCE, ONE.DEM_SOURCE_LINE, ONE.DEM_PART_ID, ONE.[PART ID DESCRIPTION], ONE.DEM_QTY, ONE.ACUM_ASSIGN_QTY, ONE.ASSIGNED_QTY, ONE.SUPPLY_TYPE, ONE.SUPPLY_SOURCE, ONE.SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE, ONE.SUPPLY_QTY, ONE.REST_QTY, ONE.SUPPLIER, ONE.[PO STATUS], ONE.[WO STATUS],   ONE.[SO CREATED DATE], ONE.[WO CREATED DATE], ONE.[SO PROMISE SHIP DATE PER LINE], ONE.[WO RELEASE DATE], ONE.[PO PLACE DATE], ONE.[SITE ARRIVAL], ONE.[UPDATE SHIP DATE], ONE.[INITIAL SHIP DATE], ONE.[LEAD TIME PROVIDE]  AS 'LEAD TIME PROVIDE BY SCHEDULER', ONE.[LEAD TIME REQUIRED TO SUPPLIER], ONE.[LEAD TIME STANDARD], ONE.[QUALITY WAREHOUSE], ONE.COMMENTS, ONE.[SO LINK ERP], ONE.[SO LINE LINK ERP], ONE.[PARENT LINK SO ERP], ONE.[PARENT LINK SO LINE ERP], ONE.PLSO_ERP_CREATE_DATE, ONE.PLSO_ERP_SHIPPED_DATE
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN  (SELECT TOP 1 DEM_SOURCE FROM ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY  WHERE SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO' AND SUPPLY_SOURCE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE AND SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE_LINE ORDER BY DEM_PART_ID, DEM_DATE) ELSE NULL END AS 'PARENT LINK SO AUT'
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN  (SELECT TOP 1 DEM_SOURCE_LINE FROM ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY  WHERE SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO' AND SUPPLY_SOURCE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE AND SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE_LINE ORDER BY DEM_PART_ID, DEM_DATE) ELSE NULL END AS 'PARENT LINK SO LINE AUT'
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN  (SELECT TOP 1 [PLSO_ERP_CREATE_DATE] FROM ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY  WHERE SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO' AND SUPPLY_SOURCE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE AND SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE_LINE ORDER BY DEM_PART_ID, DEM_DATE) ELSE NULL END AS 'PLSO AUT CREATED DATE'
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN  (SELECT TOP 1 [PLSO_ERP_SHIPPED_DATE] FROM ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY  WHERE SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO' AND SUPPLY_SOURCE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE AND SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE_LINE ORDER BY DEM_PART_ID, DEM_DATE) ELSE NULL END AS 'PLSO AUT SHIPPED DATE'
    FROM ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY ONE
    ORDER BY ONE.DEM_PART_ID, ONE.DEM_DATE
    DROP INDEX ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY.IDX_TMP
```

[Table result part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYHt2.png)
[Table result part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDGcK.png)

As you can see, at Row no. 8 the **DEM_TYPE** is a 'WO' with a **DEM_SOURCE** with a value of 12900 and a **DEM_SOURCE_LINE** with a value of 1 (table result part 1) so in this case the 4 sub-query  will run (table result part 2)

*In the picture no. 2 , the columns **PLSO AUT CREATED DATE**  and  **PLSO AUT SHIPPED DATE** are NULL, this es valid, because it can exist those records or not

---

### Sub-Query logic

The logic about this stuff is: I have to find the DEM_SOURCE in SUPPLY_SOURCE and DEM_SOURCE_LINE IN SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE in whole table, i mean for example we return to the row number 8.

if we take the row no. 8 we have these Values... DEM_TYPE = 'WO', DEM_SOURCE: 12900 and DEM_SOURCE_LINE = 1, i can get the sub-query ready to search and get the 4 extra columns for this row like this:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 DEM_SOURCE FROM ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY  WHERE SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO' AND SUPPLY_SOURCE = '12900' AND SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE = '1')
```

[Sub-query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pGga.png)

and if you check the picture no. 2 , these 4 values will be in the last 4 columns with the 4 names that we talked at the beginning ... These process i have to do it for each row when DEM_TYPE is 'WO', someone know how i can improve it? i tried with an index, it helps but is not faster enough.
Thank you so much for take your time reading this post, please if you have some questions or some advice please let me know!

Comment: It sounds like you want to join.  Have you tried creating a temp table or CTE of only the results you wanna filter by, then joining to that (since you mentioned you are looking at the same table multiple times)?

Comment: I'm concerned that all your subqueries use `SELECT TOP 1...` with no `ORDER BY`

Comment: @TTeeple yes i tried, but i couldn't get the answer, when i tried  use a LEFT JOIN i got more rows than the original table and this is because the LEFT JOIN is getting the all rows in the MATCH and i just wanted the first, and the CTE i don't know how to handled it in this case

Comment: If the left join increases the row count, you are not using a unique key to join the tables. This is bad because that means you can not be sure what value will be selected if you use TOP 1 without an ORDER BY. If the key contains multiple of the same value use a DISTINCT or a GROUP BY to prevent row increase

Comment: Why do you create a unique index on the main table, only to drop it after the query? You should create it once and leave it there or not use it at all.

Comment: To explain why you should use a join: your current query performs the subqueries PER ROW.  A proper left join is executed once.

Comment: @J.D. yes i agree with use join, i'll try it again with the LEFT JOIN, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading all data in one query is kinda bad practice in my opinion. If it's for lazy load to cache data somewhere, then maybe that's acceptable, but if you're trying to load data for user then paging would be better option.

I hope that you created indexing for `SUPPLY_TYPE`, `SUPPLY_SOURCE`, `SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE` as it could improve query time.

For your question you could use `OUTER APPLY` - [Sql server cross apply and outer apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

My non-tested and fast reply would be (still has space to be modified):

```
SELECT
    ONE.ROWID, ONE.PLANNER, ONE.BUYER, ONE.DEM_TYPE, ONE.DEM_SOURCE, ONE.DEM_SOURCE_LINE, ONE.DEM_PART_ID, ONE.[PART ID DESCRIPTION], ONE.DEM_QTY, ONE.ACUM_ASSIGN_QTY, ONE.ASSIGNED_QTY, ONE.SUPPLY_TYPE, ONE.SUPPLY_SOURCE, ONE.SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE, ONE.SUPPLY_QTY, ONE.REST_QTY, ONE.SUPPLIER, ONE.[PO STATUS], ONE.[WO STATUS],   ONE.[SO CREATED DATE], ONE.[WO CREATED DATE], ONE.[SO PROMISE SHIP DATE PER LINE], ONE.[WO RELEASE DATE], ONE.[PO PLACE DATE], ONE.[SITE ARRIVAL], ONE.[UPDATE SHIP DATE], ONE.[INITIAL SHIP DATE], ONE.[LEAD TIME PROVIDE]  AS 'LEAD TIME PROVIDE BY SCHEDULER', ONE.[LEAD TIME REQUIRED TO SUPPLIER], ONE.[LEAD TIME STANDARD], ONE.[QUALITY WAREHOUSE], ONE.COMMENTS, ONE.[SO LINK ERP], ONE.[SO LINE LINK ERP], ONE.[PARENT LINK SO ERP], ONE.[PARENT LINK SO LINE ERP], ONE.PLSO_ERP_CREATE_DATE, ONE.PLSO_ERP_SHIPPED_DATE
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN [Table2].[DEM_SOURCE] ELSE NULL END AS 'PARENT LINK SO AUT'
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN [Table2].[DEM_SOURCE_LINE] ELSE NULL END AS 'PARENT LINK SO LINE AUT'
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN [Table2].[PLSO_ERP_CREATE_DATE] ELSE NULL END AS 'PLSO AUT CREATED DATE'
    ,CASE WHEN ONE.DEM_TYPE = 'WO' THEN [Table2].[PLSO_ERP_SHIPPED_DATE] ELSE NULL END AS 'PLSO AUT SHIPPED DATE'
FROM
    ENT_DEMAN_SUPPLY ONE
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        DEM_SOURCE
        ,DEM_SOURCE_LINE
        ,PLSO_ERP_CREATE_DATE
        ,PLSO_ERP_SHIPPED_DATE
    FROM
        ENT_DEMAND_SUPPLY [TWO]
    WHERE --These columns should be indexed
        [TWO].SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO'
        AND [TWO].SUPPLY_SOURCE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE
        AND [TWO].SUPPLY_SOURCE_LINE = ONE.DEM_SOURCE_LINE
) [Table2]
ORDER BY ONE.DEM_PART_ID, ONE.DEM_DATE
```

Comment: Hi there thank so much for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't work, i got the 4 last columns in NULL, i'll be checking `OUTER APPLY` thanks for for tip!

Comment: Before I edited my answer there was `[TWO].[ROWID] = [ONE].[ROWID]`, try to remove that

Comment: Wait there! i just removed the first **WHERE** condition in [Table2] that is the row id equal to the other row id and it works! Now only takes 23 secs, and the indexes are not there yet! i'll let you know how will end Thanks

Comment: It works perfectly! 1 sec doing the **Select** thanks a lot.